# $f$ analytic in unit disc then there is $h$ such that $f(z)=(h(z))^n$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Question:

If $f(z)\neq 0$ for any $z\in D$, where $D$ is the unit disc, then show for any integer $n$ there exists a function $h(z)$ analytic in $D$ such that $f(z)=(h(z))^n$.

After observation, $D$ is simply connected so $f$ has primitive in $D$ and there exists $g$ such that $f=e^{g(z)}$, if I take logarithm on both sides, then there exists $g$ such that $\log{f(z)}=g(z)$, then what should I do? Am I on the right direction?

Could anyone kindly help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: try $\exp(g(z)/n)$.
${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks so much for the hint! Following the hint, let $f=e^{(g(z)/n)n}$, then if $h(z)=e^{g(z)/n}$, $h$ is analytic since $g$ is analytic, then $f(z)=(h(z))^n$. Is this the right way?

Comment: @Sherry you used the word "let" a bit oddly, however, that reasoning is correct!